# How to assign different colors to different edges using igraph in Python?

Tags: python, plot, igraph, edges

I have a graph with three kinds of edges: 'company', 'std' and 'res'. Many other vertices have no edges.

When I plot a summary, I get:

```
IGRAPH UN-- 500 36 -- 
+ attr: area (v), cnpj (v), grande_area (v), name (v), res (v), std (v), company (e), res (e), std (e)
```

I want to plot the different kinds of edges in different colors, but I cannot find the right code.

Here is a sample of what I get when I print the edges:

```
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x00000000045A4B88>, 7, {'res': True, 'company': None, 'std': None})
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x00000000045A4B88>, 8, {'res': True, 'company': None, 'std': None})
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x00000000045A4B88>, 9, {'res': True, 'company': None, 'std': None})
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x00000000045A4B88>, 10, {'res': None, 'company': True, 'std': None})
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x00000000045A4B88>, 11, {'res': True, 'company': None, 'std': None})
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x00000000045A4B88>, 12, {'res': None, 'company': True, 'std': None})
```

The code I used to make the edges is:

```
def edge_group(g):
    for v in g.vs:
        for w in g.vs:
            if v != w:
                if g.are_connected(v, w) is False:
                    if v['name'].get_cnpj() != "":
                        if v["name"].get_cnpj() == w["name"].get_cnpj():
                            g.add_edge(v, w, company=True)
                    if len(set(v['std']).intersection(w['std'])) > 0:
                        g.add_edge(v, w, std=True)
                    if len(set(v['res']).intersection(w['res'])) > 0:
                        g.add_edge(v, w, res=True)
    return g
```

And here is the code that is giving me all edges 'black'

```
def drawing_group(g):
    layout = g.layout("fr")
    visual_style = {}
    visual_style["vertex_size"] = 1
    if g.es["company"] is True and g.es['res'] is True and g.es['std'] is True:
        visual_style['edge_color'] = 'black'
    if g.es["company"] is True and g.es['res'] is True:
        visual_style['edge_color'] = 'grey'
    if g.es["company"] is True and g.es['std'] is True:
        visual_style['edge_color'] = 'green'
    if g.es['company'] is True:
        visual_style['edge_color'] = 'blue'
    if g.es['res'] is True and g.es['std'] is True:
        visual_style['edge_color'] = 'red'
    if g.es['res'] is True:
        visual_style['edge_color'] = 'yellow'
    if g.es['std'] is True:
        visual_style['edge_color'] = 'brown'
    visual_style["layout"] = layout
    visual_style["bbox"] = (500, 500)
    visual_style["margin"] = 20
    visual_style['hovermode'] = 'closest'

    igraph.plot(g, 'output/gr_%s.png' % num, **visual_style)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that does work.

```
def drawing_group(g, name='a'):
    layout = g.layout("fr")
    visual_style = {}
    for e in g.es:
        if e['company'] is True:
            e['color'] = 'blue'
        elif e['res'] is True:
            e['color'] = 'red'
        elif e['std'] is True:
            e['color'] = 'green'
    visual_style["vertex_size"] = 1
    visual_style["layout"] = layout
    visual_style["bbox"] = (500, 500)
    visual_style["margin"] = 20
    visual_style['hovermode'] = 'closest'
    igraph.plot(g, 'output/gr_%s.png' % (str(num) + name), **visual_style)
```

However, I feel there is a glitch in python. I have to keep recreating the original graph because, somehow, python is keeping the memory of the edges I add even if I change the name of the graph. If I don't repeat the command `g_groups_all = body.create_groups_edges(g_groups)` the edges are created on top of each other... As if everytime I use g_groups to add edges I am changing g_groups itself! Go figure!

```
g_student = body.create_groups_edges_std(g_groups)
g_groups = body.create_vertex_groups(my_groups)
g_researcher = body.create_groups_edges_res(g_groups)
g_groups = body.create_vertex_groups(my_groups)
g_company = body.create_groups_edges_company(g_groups)
g_groups = body.create_vertex_groups(my_groups)
g_groups_all = body.create_groups_edges(g_groups)
```